# Is there a "faxto" or similar protocol?

Tags: html, hyperlink, uri, anchor, fax

I have a client with a fax number, and after linking their address to Google Maps, their email with a `mailto:`, and their phone with a `callto:`*, I felt wrong leaving their fax number unlinked. **Is there any way I can link a fax number?**

> `*` I would use `tel:`, as that is an actual standard, but `callto:` is more supported

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As indicated by @Jukka, the fax URL scheme from the rfc2806 specs has been obsoleted by RFC 3966. So you should just be able to use tel: for Fax numbers also.

From the RFC 3966 Specs - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt

> The identifier approach described in this document has the
>      disadvantage that certain services, such as electronic banking or
>      voicemail, cannot be specified in a `"tel"` URI.
>
> The notation for phone numbers in this document is similar to that in
>      RFC 3191 [RFC3191] and RFC 3192 [RFC3192].  However, the syntax
>      differs as this document describes URIs whereas RFC 3191 and RFC 3192
>      specify electronic mail addresses.  RFC 3191 and RFC 3192 use "/" to
>      indicate parameters (qualifiers).  Since URIs use the forward slash
>      to describe path hierarchy, the URI scheme described here uses the
>      semicolon, in keeping with Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) URI
>      conventions [RFC3261].
>
> The "tel" URI can be used as a request URI in SIP [RFC3261] requests.
>      The SIP specification also inherits the 'subscriber' part of the
>      syntax as part of the 'user element' in the SIP URI.  Other protocols
>      may also use this URI scheme.
>
> The "tel" URI does not specify the call type, such as voice, fax, or
>      data call, and does not provide the connection parameters for a data
>      call.  The type and parameters are assumed to be negotiated either
>      in-band by the telephone device or through a signaling protocol such
>      as SIP.
>
> This document obsoletes RFC 2806.

**OBSOLETE ANSWER**

Yes. Use it like so.

```
<a href="fax:+415.123.4567>+415.123.4567</a>
```

Depending on Global or Local number, you use the `+` or `*` prefix. Recommend you use the global notation.

The tel, fax and modem URL Schemes are discussed in rfc2806 specs  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806

Here's the relevant section

#### 2.3 "fax" URL scheme

> The URL syntax is formally described as follows (the definition
>      reuses nonterminals from the above definition). For the basis of this
>      syntax, see [RFC2303] and [RFC2304].

```
  fax-url          = fax-scheme ":" fax-subscriber
  fax-scheme       = "fax"
  fax-subscriber   = fax-global-phone / fax-local-phone
  fax-global-phone = "+" base-phone-number [isdn-subaddress]
                     [t33-subaddress] [post-dial]
                     *(area-specifier / service-provider /
                     future-extension)
  fax-local-phone  = 1*(phonedigit / dtmf-digit /
                     pause-character) [isdn-subaddress]
                     [t33-subaddress] [post-dial]
                     area-specifier
                     *(area-specifier / service-provider /
                     future-extension)
  t33-subaddress   = ";tsub=" 1*phonedigit
```

Comment: RFC 2806 was obsoleted by RFC 3966 in 2004. RFC 3966 defines `tel:` URLs as being applicable to faxes, too.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the RFC 3966 and you are right. Updated my answer.

Comment: So... their computer is supposed to magically know that the `tel` link references a fax number, and launch a fax app rather than, say, Skype?

Comment: I'll have to see how others people have implemented this. I don't have access to a fax #. Did you try the code on your test machine?

Comment: @Shiva I don't have a fax machine, and clicking `tel:` links in general doesn't do anything.  If you need a test fax number, then go to any university's site; they'll have one somewhere.